# How to get aggregate and column data from Derby database joining three tables

Tags: java, swing, derby

I need to present data from a Derby database in a JTable, but two of the columns are aggregate sums from two one-to-many related tables. Here are example schema:

```
SHIFTDATA:
    ID
    DATE
    SHIFT
    FOOD_COST
    OFFICE_SUPPLIES
    REP_MAINT
    NET_SALES
    SALES_TAX

OTHERPAIDOUTS:
    ID
    SHIFTDATA_ID
    LABEL
    AMOUNT

DISCOUNTS
    ID
    SHIFTDATA_ID
    DISCOUNT_NAME
    AMOUNT
```

There are 0 or more OTHERPAIDOUTS for a given SHIFTDATA

There are 0 or more DISCOUNTS for a given SHIFTDATA

I need the equivalent of this statement, though I know I can’t combine aggregate expressions with "non-aggregate expressions" in a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT (S.FOOD_COST + S.OFFICE_SUPPLIES + S.REP_MAINT + SUM(O.AMOUNT)) AS TOTAL_PAIDOUTS, 
SUM(D.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_DISCOUNT, 
S.NET_SALES,
S.SALES_TAX
FROM SHIFTDATA S, OTHERPAIDOUTS O, DISCOUNTS D WHERE O.SHIFTDATA_ID=S.ID AND D.SHIFTDATA_ID=S.ID
```

I see in other threads where adding the GROUP BY clause fixes these situations, but I guess adding in the second aggregate from a third table is throwing me off. I tried GROUP BY S.NET_SALES, S.SALES_TAX, and adding AND S.ID = 278 to the WHERE clause to get a known result, and the TOTAL_PAIDOUTS is correct (there are 3 related records in OTHERPAIDOUTS), but the returned TOTAL_DISCOUNTS is 3 times what it should be.

Needless to say, I’m not a SQL programmer! Hopefully you get the gist of what I’m after. I tried nested SELECT statements but just made a mess of it. This application is still in development, including the database structure, so if a different DB structure would simplify things, that may be an option. Or, if there's another way to programmatically build the table model, I'm open to that as well. Thanks in advance!!

======== Edit =============

In order to check the values from a known record, I'm querying with a specific SHIFTDATA.ID. Following is the sample table records:

```
SHIFTDATA:
ID  |FOOD_COST |OFFICE_SU&|REP_MAINT |NET_SALES |SALES_TAX
------------------------------------------------------
278 |0.00      |5.00      |10.00     |3898.78   |319.79

OTHERPAIDOUTS:
ID         |SHIFTDATA_&|LABEL                                   |AMOUNT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
37         |278        |FOOD COST FUEL                          |52.00
38         |278        |MAINT FUEL                              |5.00
39         |278        |EMPLOYEE SHOES                          |21.48

DISCOUNTS:
ID         |ITEM_NAME                               |SHIFTDATA_&|AMOUNT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
219        |Misc Discounts                          |278        |15.91
```

What I expect to see for this SHIFTDATA row in the JTable:

```
TOTAL_PAIDOUTS | TOTAL_DISCOUNT |NET_SALES |SALES_TAX
------------------------------------------------------
93.48          |15.91           |3898.78   |319.79
```

The best I can get is by adding the GROUP BY clause, but grouping by the fields from SHIFTDATA I get:

```
TOTAL_PAIDOUTS | TOTAL_DISCOUNT |NET_SALES |SALES_TAX
------------------------------------------------------
93.48          |47.73           |3898.78   |319.79
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input table data -and- the output to be shown in the `JTable`?

Comment: I'll edit my OP since I'm limited on comment length.

Comment: Sure,. You can add it at the bottom of your post!

Comment: How did you arrive at the value `93.48` for `TOTAL_PAIDOUTS`?

Comment: That's the result of 
    S.FOOD_COST + S.OFFICE_SUPPLIES + S.REP_MAINT + SUM(O.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PAIDOUTS

Comment: What is `SUM(O.AMOUNT)`?

Comment: That's what's used in the original SELECT statement, SUM of the AMOUNT field from the OTHERPAIDOUTS table. That part of the query works fine -- if I add GROUP BY S.FOOD_COST, S.OFFICE_SUPPLIES, S.REP_MAINT -- but the SUM of DISCOUNTS.AMOUNT is multiplied by 3, presumably due to the three rows from OTHERPAIDOUTS.

Thanks for the interest so far! I'm at the end of my shift (it's 06:00 where I'm at) so I won't be checking back until about 20:00 my time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SQL query with required result.

Here are the table definitions, data, sql and the results:

```
CREATE TABLE shiftdata (
    id int,
    foodcost int,
    officesuppl int,
    repmaint int,
    netsales int,
    salestax int);

CREATE TABLE otherpaidouts (
    id int,
    shiftid int,
    label varchar(20),
    amount int);

CREATE TABLE discounts (
    id int,
    shiftid int,
    itemname varchar(20),
    amount int);
```

Create data for two shifts: 278 and 333. Both shifts have `discounts`, but only 278 shift has the `otherpaidouts`.

```
insert into shiftdata values (278, 0, 5, 10, 3898, 319);
insert into shiftdata values (333, 22, 15, 100, 2111, 88);
insert into otherpaidouts values (37, 278, 'Food Cost FUEL', 52);
insert into otherpaidouts values (38, 278, 'Maint FUEL', 5);
insert into otherpaidouts values (39, 278, 'Empl SHOES', 21);
insert into discounts values (219, 278, 'Misc DISCOUNTS', 15);
insert into discounts values (312, 333, 'Misc DISCOUNTS', 25);
```

*The Query:*

```
SELECT sd.id, sd.netsales, sd.salestax,
  IFNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(d.amount) FROM discounts d WHERE d.shiftid=sd.id), 0) AS total_discount,
  (SELECT sd.foodcost + sd.officesuppl + sd.repmaint + IFNULL(SUM(op.amount), 0) FROM otherpaidouts op WHERE op.shiftid=sd.id) AS total_paidouts
FROM shiftdata sd;
```

*The Result:*

```
+------+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+
| id   | netsales | salestax | total_discount | total_paidouts |
+------+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+
|  278 |     3898 |      319 |             15 |             93 |
|  333 |     2111 |       88 |             25 |            137 |
+------+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Man. That looks really good, but I don't see an `IFNULL` function in Derby.

Comment: Man. I knew you were onto something. What I did find is the `COALESCE` function, which works exactly the same! You did it! Very, VERY grateful! That was a lot of work you went through, thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking MYSQL (MySQL has `COALESCE`)! Yes, I have worked little bit with Apache Derby, (aka JavaDB) but thanks for pointing it. Most of the database related posts on SO are MySQL, and I didn't notice it was Derby.

Answer (score 1):

Try a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html#rrefsqlj18922), something like this:

```
SELECT S.FOOD_COST + S.OFFICE_SUPPLIES + S.REP_MAINT + SUM(O.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PAIDOUTS, 
       SUM(D.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_DISCOUNT, 
       S.NET_SALES,
       S.SALES_TAX
FROM SHIFTDATA S
LEFT JOIN OTHERPAIDOUTS AS O ON O.SHIFTDATA_ID = S.ID
LEFT JOIN DISCOUNTS AS D     ON D.SHIFTDATA_ID = S.ID
```

## Edit

```
SELECT S.FOOD_COST + S.OFFICE_SUPPLIES + S.REP_MAINT +
       ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) FROM OTHERPAIDOUTS WHERE SHIFTDATA_ID = S.ID ) AS TOTAL_PAIDOUTS,
       ( SELECT COALESCE(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) FROM DISCOUNTS     WHERE SHIFTDATA_ID = S.ID ) AS TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
       S.NET_SALES,
       S.SALES_TAX
FROM SHIFTDATA S
```

Comment: Thanks, but with that I get the "When the SELECT list contains at least one aggregate then all entries must be valid aggregate expressions". So far, all questions I've seen that ask about mixing aggregates with non-aggregates say that a GROUP BY clause must be included. The only GROUP BY clause I can get to work at all is listing the individual field names (S.FOOD_COST, S.OFFICE_SUPPLIES, etc), and the TOTAL_DISCOUNT amount is the actual amount multiplied by the number of OTHERPAIDOUTS records for each SHIFTDATA.

Comment: That's it! Thanks SO much!

Comment: Check that. That query returns correct results if `SUM(AMOUNT) FROM OTHERPAIDOUTS` is not null. If it's null I don't still get the sum of the `SHIFTDATA` columns.